# how can i change the shape mouse cursor in gWidgets RGtk2?

Tags: r, gwidgets

In a Drawing Area of ggraphics in gWidgets changes  the mouse cursor to "GDK_TCROSS",but  i want the same mouse cursor of the gwindow "GDK_LEFT_PTR":

```
 library(gWidgets)
 library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
 library(RGtk2)
 options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
 w=gwindow("")
 g=ggraphics(cont=w,no_popup=T,do.rubber.banding = F)
 plot(x,y)
 c=gdkCursorNew("GDK_TOP_LEFT_ARROW")
 getToolkitWidget(g)$ModifyCursor(c)

  or

 gtkWidgetModifyCursor(getToolkitWidget(g),"GDK_TCROSS","GDK_LEFT_PTR")
```

but this not works

Answer (score 1):

`gtkWidgetModifyCursor` modifies the colors of the cursor. You need to set the cursor through `gdkWindowSetCursor`. For that you need to grab the window associated with the widget:

```
getToolkitWidget(g)$getWindow()$setCursor(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i change or i update the graphic in this area ggraphics, again leaves  the default mouse cursor "GDK_TCROSS"

Comment: Interesting. This also happens if you just use `RGtk2` and `cairoDevice` without `gWidgets`. I can only suggest looking to see if there is some event signalled when a plot is drawn and change the cursor each time this happens.

Comment: Many Thanks, i'll do this way