# RGtk cursor shapes

Tags: r, gwidgets

Morning,

I'm currently building a R/Gtk2 application (mostly through gWidgets actually) and I would like to change the cursor shape to something sensible in different contexts. Specifically, I require a "zoom in" and "zoom out" shape when the appropriate tool is activated.

This post ([how can i change the shape mouse cursor in gWidgets RGtk2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309532/how-can-i-change-the-shape-mouse-cursor-in-gwidgets-rgtk2)) gives good information on the syntax to use.

My problem is that in the list of available cursors (e.g. `help("gdk-Cursors")` ) includes all sort of weird and wonderful things (boat, clock and coffee mug....) but none of the ordinary shapes such as zoom in, zoom out, text edit...

I guess I could use an external image to define cursor I like (cf. [Change mouse cursor of a widget in gWidgetsRGtk2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657985/change-mouse-cursor-of-a-widget-in-gwidgetsrgtk2)) but really, I find it hard to believe that RGtk does not ship with a set of sane cursor shapes.

Surely I'm missing something, but where can I find cursors of "normal" shape ?

Comment: I'm not sure these all work with Gtk2, but does this help: `https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name`?

Comment: It probably should but I'm not familiar enough with GTK to be able to use it :-/ thanks anyway.